# Set one-to-one association in sequelize

Tags: mysql, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I am trying to get a single one-to-one association. This is my code:

- Provider code

```
const Provider = sequelize.define("provider", {
    idProvider: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    idUser: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      //unique: true,
    },
    isPublicProvider: {
      type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    },
  });

  Provider.associate = function (models) {
    Provider.hasOne(models.user, {
      through: "users",
      as: "idUser",
      foreignKey: "idUser",
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
    });
  };
```

In the association part, I have to get one IdUser only from this table

- User code

```
const User = sequelize.define("user", {
    idUser: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      unique: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    nameUser: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      validate: { notEmpty: true },
    },
    emailUser: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      unique: true,
      validate: { isEmail: true },
    },
    activeUser: {
      type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    },
  });

  User.associate = (model) => {
    User.belongsTo(models.Group, {
      through: "providers",
      as: "idUser",
      foreignKey: "idUser",
    });
  };
```

When I check the ERR model, there is no relation between

[This is a image from my diagram] https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWqOo.png

Thanks to all before answer :)

Comment: Where is a Group model definition and associations?

Comment: According to your diagram User and Providers does not linked by any foreign keys

Comment: `through` options makes sense only for belongsToMany association